# spring rabbitmq and UI layer or managed bean

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a rabbitmq listener as a separate class and JSF 2 managed bean.

In my bean I send a message and need to wait for result. I can't use sendAndReceive... because I send the message to one queue but receive from another queue, so I assign correlationId before sending.

So I need to wait asynchronously, I need to wait until right message comes to the listener. How to do it in rmq?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html) and [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.java#L974) of RabbitTemplate it seems that he waits for response in reply queue. Do you set 'reply-to' property in your messages? If yes, then RabbitTemplate sendAndReceive methods should wait for response in 'reply-to' queue. Be sure to populate [replyTo field](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/core/MessageProperties.html#setReplyTo-java.lang.String-) correctly and test it.

Side note:
In RabbitMQ you do not send messages to the queue.
You send messages to the exchanges. Exchanges are routing messages to the queue(s) using bindings. With default or direct exchange type it looks like you send directly to the queue, but this is over-simplification.

See https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html for details.

Edit:
It seems there are some fix for that in AMQP 1.4.5.RELEASE
https://spring.io/blog/2015/05/08/spring-amqp-1-4-5-release-and-1-5-0-m1-available

> **Configurable Exchange/Routing Key for Replies**
>
> Previously, when using request/reply messaging with the
>   RabbitTemplate, replies were routed to the default exchange and routed
>   with the queue name. It is now possible to supply a reply-address with
>   the form exchange/routingKey to route using a specific exchange and
>   routing key.

Comment: Thank you! but the issue is I can`t use reply queues as I will send messages to 2 or more queues via an exchange, and from another, 'reply' queue I will need to take the result for displaying it to the customer. So I will have to listen for my 'reply' queue and grab result from there when it comes. I just wondered is there a way to take a message by correlationID directly, sth like rabbitTemplate.getByCorrId(String corrId). Now I use synchronized map and put corrIds there, and when message comes to 'reply' queue, I check it and remove from map. Is it ok? How do you think?

Comment: If I specify reply=to property for a message, it gives me error sth like 'you can`t use sendAndReceive  with reply-to property', so I guess I can set it only for listener/adapter, but it`s not applicable fro me. Thank you